# For multi-troop cards does Damage Per Second apply to each troop or all troops collectively?

Tags: clash-royale

For example, the Barbarians card, which spawns 5 barbarians, shows DPS as 165 at level 13. Does this mean each barbarian does 165 DPS or is it 33 DPS per barbarian (165/5)?

See also: Minion Horde,Royal Hogs,Fire spirits, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The damage values are **per individual**.

You can see this by comparing cards of the same type (Minions, Horde or Skeletons, Skarmy). They will show the same damage and health values, thus ignoring the amount of troops the card spawns.

For example:

- [Minion Horde](https://clashroyale.fandom.com/wiki/Minion_Horde) Lv 13 = 123 dps
- [Minions](https://clashroyale.fandom.com/wiki/Minions) Lv. 13 = 123 dps

or

- [Skeletons](https://clashroyale.fandom.com/wiki/Skeletons) Lv. 13 = 98 dps
- [Skarmy](https://clashroyale.fandom.com/wiki/Skeleton_Army) Lv. 13 = 98 dps

This of course applies to all multi-troop cards.